# Mathematical power operations in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Please help!! A client work is asking us to perform mathematical power function. How to perform mathematical power function in android studio?

Comment: What have you tried and does it throw error codes? If you haven't tried anything, the question is better suited to Google. Not a QA site.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Math.pow(x,y) means x<sup>y</sup>.